# Datepicker reads variables from text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datepicker

Can someone show me how to make the code below get its disabled dates variables (12-12-2017 and 9-12-2017) from a separate text file instead of from inside the script? I have tried many methods to no avail. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Code:

```
<!--start datepicker -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var unavailableDates = ["12-12-2017","9-12-2017"];
function unavailable(date) {
dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
    return [true, ""];
} 
else {
    return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
}
}

$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', 
      beforeShowDay: unavailable,
      minDate: 2,
      });
 });
</script> 
<!--end datepicker -->
```

Comment: Are the dates static or dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a REST api to get the disabled dates.

Comment: You will write a function on the server to read a file and return the dates (or whatever data present in the text file) to your web application.